# networking works on simulator does not work on iPhone device

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking, simulator

This code works flawlessly on the simulator, writes out the file.

On the iPhone however, it does not write the file out.

```
DLog(@"");

timeStart  = [NSDate date];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:SAT_URL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    DLog(@"updated words to: %@",path);
    //DLog(@"response: %@",responseObject);

    [self processWords];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    // Deal with failure
}];

[operation start];
```

rawWords and lines are all null on the device:

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILE_NAME];
NSString *rawWords = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *lines = [rawWords componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

This uses the AFNetworking lib and I've tried fetching the file from different hosters.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the device connected to the internet? Just checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write to a bundle (definitely not on a device, maybe it is possible in the Simulator). You can write to a few predefined directories though (Cache, Documents). Check out the following post on StackOverflow: [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains explanation confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627177/nssearchpathfordirectoriesindomains-explanation-confused)